# Animate rows through a directive inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm building this application in Angular where a div table is formed by using ng-repeat through the following html:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.data.ipv4">
    <div class="cellbody">{{value.descr}}</div>
    <div class="cellbody">{{value.protocol}}</div>
    <div class="cellbody">{{value.internip}}</div>
    <div class="cellbody">{{value.internrange}}</div>
    <div class="cellbody">{{value.externrange}}</div>
    <div class="deletecell">
        <span class="toggledelete"  ng-click="deleteport($event, key, 4)">
            <i class="icon-minus negativehover"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="toggledelete" style="display:none">
            <span>PORT DELETED</span>
            <span class="deletedportundo" ng-click="restoreport($event, $index, 4)">
                UNDO
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The last div of each row, has a visible clickable button which sends a delete order to the server via the deleteport() function, and then, if everything goes all right, starts an animation where the whole cell is hidden and the previously hidden span with class 'deletedportundo' shows up.

Anyway the thing is my controller looks like this:

**Angular Javascript Controller**

```
$scope.deleteport = function(e,f) {
    postData.index = f;
    $http.post('serverside/router.php', postData)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if (data.status == 'ok') {
                var elem = angular.element(e.target);
                $(elem).parent().parent().parent().children('.cellbody').hide('fast');
                $(elem).parent().parent().children('.toggledelete').toggle();
                $(elem).parent().parent().parent().children('.deletecell').animate({
                width: "100%"
                }, 300 );
                $(elem).parent().parent().parent().children('.deletecell').addClass('macdeleted');
            }
    });
}
```

Which visually works as expected, except that I am aware that I should not be manipulating the DOM in the controller; I have been unsuccessfully trying to integrate this into a directive, but because every row is independent of the others I have not been able to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

There is nothing wrong with manipulating DOM in the controller. However, I can suggest an easier way to do it than to navigate with those nasty  parent().parent().parent().parent().parent() ... calls :) .

Just add an `ng-show` to the toggledelete div, than just do `$scope.portDeleted = false` in your controller. This also works for the `.cellbody` tags.

As for the `.deletecell` class you can use ng-class, and just do `$scope.deletecell = some_value`.

```
<div ng-class="{deletecell:deletecell}">
    <span class="toggledelete"  ng-click="deleteport($event, key, 4)">
        <i class="icon-minus negativehover"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="toggledelete" style="display:none">
        <span>PORT DELETED</span>
        <span class="deletedportundo" ng-click="restoreport($event, $index, 4)">
            UNDO
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

For animate, you can use ngAnimate (http://www.nganimate.org/)